# What are the caps lock and scroll lock keys for?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

Every keyboard I have ever seen contained a caps lock and scroll lock key. However, I have never figured out what scroll lock is for, and the caps lock key has always annoyed me (I have disabled it using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) :-). I wonder what both keys are good for. Is there anyone who really uses these keys? And is there anybody who knows why you can't buy a keyboard without them?

Comment: I've seen people typing capital letters by hitting Caps, letter, Caps again. Instead of just using shift :-)

Comment: caps lock is cruise control for cool

Comment: Yes, I use the caps lock for capitalization more often than I do the shift key.

Comment: They're both awesome modifiers for when you have more hotkeys than sense :)
Scroll lock particularly, almost no noticable change, and yet can change an entire hotkeyset! Incredible!

Comment: HI, BILLY MAYS HERE FOR THE ALL NEW ALL-CAPS KEYBOARD.  TIRED OF HAVING TO HIT CAPS LOCK TO TYPE *ALL* YOUR CORRESPONDENCE?  THE NEW BILLY MAY'S KEYBOARD PREVENTS THAT BY AUTOMATICALLY ENABLING CAPS LOCK ALL THE TIME, NO MATTER WHAT.  STOP THE CAPS LOCK STRAIN, STOP THE LOWER CASE PAIN WITH THE ALL NEW BILLY MAYS KEYBOARD.  HERE'S HOW TO ORDER...

Comment: @Johannes Rossel - I've always done it like that. Never figured out why people today have trouble with the caps key.

Comment: @tj111 - do I get a set of free knives as well if I order now ?

Comment: @Dimitri C - wait till you discover "sys rq" key. That's where the interesting part starts :)

Comment: @tj111 - awesome homage :)

Comment: Please **mark an answer as accepted** if you feel your question has been fully answered (I believe your question has been adequately answered).

Comment: CAPSFree! Spread the word!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not the only person who can't see the point of `CapsLock`: [www.ihatethecapslockkey.com](http://www.ihatethecapslockkey.com/)

On that site you can find a utility to do make the CapsLock key act as different key.  But you're already doing this with [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but with AutoHotKey you can get more creative in your remapping - and make ScrollLock do something else too.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what it says on Wikipedia about the [scroll lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll_lock) key:

> The scroll lock key was meant to lock
>   all scrolling techniques, and is a
>   remnant from the original IBM PC
>   keyboard, though it is not used by
>   most modern-day software. In the
>   original design, scroll lock was
>   intended to modify the behavior of the
>   arrow keys. When the scroll lock mode
>   was on, the arrow keys would scroll
>   the contents of a text window instead
>   of moving the cursor. In this usage,
>   scroll lock is a modifier key like Alt
>   and Shift (which modify the function
>   of other keys) and, more specifically,
>   a toggling lock key like Num Lock or
>   Caps Lock, which have a state that
>   persists after the key is released.

Honestly, the only program that I know of that actually modifies its behavior when scroll lock is on is **Excel**. Other than that, I don't think there are other notable programs that use it.

I'm sure it's pretty clear what Caps lock does. Its usefulness is a bit limited, but I still use it from time to time.

Comment: Actually, Linux TTY's stop their scroll down when the lock is activated. However, you specify **notable**, so I'm going to let you decide if you want to include them. (However, dreamlax has this covered).

Answer (score 7):

The Linux virtual consoles pause the scrolling of output when scroll-lock is turned on (locking the scrolling, I suppose).

Since I very rarely use caps-lock, I remapped it to the “compose” key, which allows me to press a sequence of keys to produce a “composite” character. For example, when I press <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, <kbd>/</kbd>, <kbd>o</kbd>, then I get the character ø.

I suppose caps-lock would be very suitable to COBOL developers, since they are always yelling their code.

Comment: +1 for mentioning the TTY. That seems to be an oft-forgotten function.

Answer (score 5):

the reason that the caps lock key is in such an annoying location (prime pinky real-estate for such a seldom-used command) is a legacy from old typewriters.

Back before the days of electronics, the caps lock key was attached to a mechanism that physically held down the shift key, so it had to be adjacent to <kbd>shift</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I have my caps lock key set up for [Humanized Enso](http://humanized.com/).  Enso is a launcher on Windows, very similar to Quicksilver on the Mac.

However, only the other day I saw a woman typing using the caps lock instead of the shift key.  Takes all sorts, I suppose :)

Answer (score 2):

Double tapping the Scroll Lock is used by many KVM switches to switch screens.  I suppose it was chosen because it's rarely used for anything else any more.

Some (e.g. Mac) keyboards label the PrintScreen, Scroll Lock and Pause/Break keys F13, F14 and F15 but they appear to have the same function when connected to a PC.

Answer (score 2):

Scroll lock is also used by Lotus Notes. When scroll lock is enabled, [Lotus Notes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21164659) will scroll the page.

Answer (score 2):

I guess, no one is old enough to remember the real reason for the caps lock key. Yes, it comes from the typewriters. You see, typewriters did not have these fancy fonts we are all used to. They just had two types of letters: upper and lower case. So, when you wrote your MEMO, or your RESUME, or your TPS REPORT, you would write these titles in capital letters, as you would every SECTION HEADER, and everything you would now put in BOLDFACE or ITALICS (well, some fancy typewriters had italics).

Why Apple still ships the Macbook with a caps lock key, including a built-in tiny LED, is a mystery to me.

Comment: Pretty much every keyboard still has a caps lock key..

Answer (score 1):

The Caps Lock key is used for capitalization, when you do not wish to keep holding down the Shift key. This can be for when you wish to type out a string of capitalized letters, or in general for people like me. LOL.

I find the scroll lock indispensable with my KVM setup - most KVM devices, AFAIK, uses a combination like ScrLck-ScrLck-Enter or ScrLck-ScrLck-1/2/3/4 as hotkeys to switch between devices.

Answer (score 0):

In the Cobol programming language, sentences are generally encoded in capital letters. That's what the caps lock key is for on keyboards.

```
   PROGRAM-ID.   CANCELA.
  *AUTHOR. EDUARDO PALMEYRO
  *INSTALLATION. EDUSAM.
  *DATE-COMPILED.
  *DATE WRITTEN. XX/XX/XX.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
  * RUTINA DE CANCELACION  GENERA DIVISION POR CERO
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*

   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   CONFIGURATION SECTION.
   SPECIAL-NAMES. DECIMAL-POINT IS COMMA.

   DATA DIVISION.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*

   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   77  WS-CN-1                              PIC 9     VALUE 1.
   77  WS-CN-0                              PIC 9     VALUE 0.
   77  WS-CICLO                             PIC X     VALUE ' '.
       88 88-CICLO-INICIAL                            VALUE ' '.
       88 88-CICLO-CONTINUACION                       VALUE '1'.
   77  MSG                                  PIC X(50) VALUE ' '.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   LINKAGE SECTION.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
  * COPY DE AREA DE COMUNICACION CON ESTA RUTINA

   COPY WCANCELA.

  *-------------------------------------------------------------*
   PROCEDURE DIVISION USING WCANCELA.
  *-------------------------------------------------------------*

   0000-CUERPO-PRINCIPAL SECTION.
  *-----------------------------

       EVALUATE WCANCELA-CODRET (1:2)
            WHEN '00' MOVE 'SUCCESS '            TO MSG
            WHEN '02' MOVE 'SUCCESS DUPLICATE '  TO MSG
            WHEN '04' MOVE 'SUCCESS INCOMPLETE ' TO MSG
            WHEN '05' MOVE 'SUCCESS OPTIONAL '   TO MSG
            WHEN '07' MOVE 'SUCCESS NO UNIT '    TO MSG
            WHEN '10' MOVE 'END OF FILE '        TO MSG
            WHEN '14' MOVE 'OUT OF KEY RANGE '   TO MSG
            WHEN '21' MOVE 'KEY INVALID '        TO MSG
            WHEN '22' MOVE 'KEY EXISTS '         TO MSG
            WHEN '23' MOVE 'KEY NOT EXISTS '     TO MSG
            WHEN '30' MOVE 'PERMANENT ERROR '    TO MSG
            WHEN '31' MOVE 'INCONSISTENT FILENAME ' TO MSG
            WHEN '34' MOVE 'BOUNDARY VIOLATION ' TO MSG
            WHEN '35' MOVE 'FILE NOT FOUND '     TO MSG
            WHEN '37' MOVE 'PERMISSION DENIED '  TO MSG
            WHEN '38' MOVE 'CLOSED WITH LOCK '  TO MSG
            WHEN '39' MOVE 'CONFLICT ATTRIBUTE ' TO MSG
            WHEN '41' MOVE 'ALREADY OPEN '      TO MSG
            WHEN '42' MOVE 'NOT OPEN '          TO MSG
            WHEN '43' MOVE 'READ NOT DONE '     TO MSG
            WHEN '44' MOVE 'RECORD OVERFLOW '   TO MSG
            WHEN '46' MOVE 'READ ERROR '        TO MSG
            WHEN '47' MOVE 'INPUT DENIED '      TO MSG
            WHEN '48' MOVE 'OUTPUT DENIED '     TO MSG
            WHEN '49' MOVE 'I/O DENIED '        TO MSG
            WHEN '51' MOVE 'RECORD LOCKED '     TO MSG
            WHEN '52' MOVE 'END-OF-PAGE '       TO MSG
            WHEN '57' MOVE 'I/O LINAGE '        TO MSG
            WHEN '61' MOVE 'FILE SHARING FAILURE ' TO MSG
            WHEN '91' MOVE 'FILE NOT AVAILABLE ' TO MSG
       END-EVALUATE.


       DISPLAY ' '.
       DISPLAY '************************************************'.
       DISPLAY '*****   RUTINA DE CANCELACION PROGRAMADA   *****'.
       DISPLAY '************************************************'.
       DISPLAY '*                                               '.
       DISPLAY '* PROGRAMA     : ' WCANCELA-PROGRAMA.
       DISPLAY '* PARRAFO      : ' WCANCELA-PARRAFO.
       DISPLAY '* RECURSO      : ' WCANCELA-RECURSO.
       DISPLAY '* OPERACION    : ' WCANCELA-OPERACION.
       DISPLAY '* COD RETORNO  : ' WCANCELA-CODRET.
       DISPLAY '* MENSAJE      : ' WCANCELA-MENSAJE.
       DISPLAY '* MENSAJE-2    : ' MSG.
       DISPLAY '*                                               '.
       DISPLAY '************************************************'.
       DISPLAY '*           SE CANCELA EL PROCESO              *'.
       DISPLAY '************************************************'.

       GOBACK.
```